# is it possible to get the id of a conversation with a given microsoft team user

Tags: javascript, java, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

So i want to build in a feature that redirect my users to conversation on microsoft teams with a user of their choice, to accomplish that i need to fetch the conversation id between the two emails, i need to know if anyone has even done that or is it possible, thank you.

example : https://teams.microsoft.com/_?lm=deeplink&lmsrc=homePageWeb&cmpid=WebSignIn#/conversations/XXXXXXXXXXX@unq.gbl.spaces?ctx=chat i want to get the XXXXXXX or is there any other way arount it.

Comment: However you can fetch the conversation Id but that wouldn't help you create deep link to user chat, Teams have [Deep Link to Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) by user email to link to conversation between two users chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need the conversation id to do this - there's a way using Deep Links. Have a look in particular at [Deep linking to a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat). Essentially, you're linking to a chat with the combination of email addresses, and you can also set a topic and a starting message.

Be aware that if a chat between these users doesn't yet exist, this won't actually create the chat immediately - only when a user actually clicks the link is it created.

Comment: sure, glad to help